# Get bluetooth devices in range

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth

I am developing for Windows Desktop. I want to get the devices in range and to show then as a list to the user.

This is the code I am using:

```
HBLUETOOTH_DEVICE_FIND founded_device;

BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO device_info;
device_info.dwSize = sizeof(device_info);

BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS search_criteria;
search_criteria.dwSize = sizeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS);
search_criteria.fReturnAuthenticated = FALSE;
search_criteria.fReturnRemembered = FALSE;
search_criteria.fReturnConnected = TRUE;
search_criteria.fReturnUnknown = FALSE;
search_criteria.fIssueInquiry = FALSE;
search_criteria.cTimeoutMultiplier = 0;

founded_device = BluetoothFindFirstDevice(&search_criteria, &device_info);

if (founded_device == NULL)
{
    _tprintf(TEXT("Error: \n%s\n"), getErrorMessage(WSAGetLastError(), error));
    return -1;
}

do
{
    _tprintf(TEXT("founded device: %s\n"), device_info.szName);

} while (BluetoothFindNextDevice(founded_device, &device_info));
return 0;
```

My problem is that in the list of devices in range I always get the remembered devices. even if fReturnRemembered  is set to false.

I need to find a way to get only the devices in range without the remembered devices.

currently what I am doing is, I am trying to open a socket and try to communicate, but is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to start scan (Device Inquiry) you should change the search criteria:

```
search_criteria.fIssueInquiry = TRUE;
```

and maybe use some timeout bigger than 0.

By the way, if `BluetoothFindFirstDevice(&search_criteria, &device_info);` returns with `NULL`, it doesn't mean that it fails. It may end the search without results. You should get the error by `WSAGetLastError()` and check if it is `ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS`.

Alternative way is to use [WinSock APIs](https://web.archive.org/web/20130628121651/http://www.miniware.net/mobile/articles/viewarticle.php?id=19).

Comment: Unfortunately, the link in your article no longer seems to work.